# Menu jumping down on resize, responsive design, certain browsers only

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm currently working on [this site](http://soegaardcykler.dk/wp/) and I'm having a problem with the top menu navigation in both Safari and Chrome (latest versions). It works in Firefox, and even in the latest Internet Explorer!

[image: The site as it should look like.]

There are four responsive resolutions; the standard and biggest width, iPad portrait, iPhone landscape and iPhone portrait. The problem doesn't occur when resizing back and forth on all the resolutions except iPhone portrait. When resizing up from iPhone portrait the top menu navigation jumps down below the bottom-border of the header.

[image: The site after resizing from iPhone portrait]

I've tried looking at my mediaquery for iPhone portrait, and haven't been able to figure out what the issue is.

[image: The iPhone portrait view]

I hope you can help me with the little info I've given, it was too elaborate to throw all the code into a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug a bit more around and did some testing with different css options, I found that I actually forgot to put a height on the main-header div, and clear the container-div below it. I did this and it fixed the problem.

I know some of the code I have on i.e. the navigation isn't done exactly the way it should, but it works now on all the browsers and resolutions and that's the important part.

Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see *why* this is happening either, but if you add `overflow: hidden` to your `#main-header`, you see *what* is happening. There's a bit of a float confusion, which was a common problem in IE6 if you had right floated elements after block elements in your HTML... if you keep the hidden overflow on the header and add `float: left` to `#logo` it works for me, though.

Comment: It virtually seems to be a variation of the mentioned IE6 bug, if you put the navigation before the logo in your HTML, it works without adjusting any css.

Answer (score 1):

Your header should be handled in diffrent way your inner elements should have inline-block; header should have inline-block with width: 100% which will be affected by parent width
and it should fix your responsive problem